# JS split() function that ignores separator appearing inside quotation marks

Tags: javascript, split, quotes

Basically, like if you were to say

```
var string = 'he said "Hello World"';
var splitted = string.split(" ");
```

the splitted array would be:

```
'he' 'said' '"Hello World"'
```

basically treating the quotation mark'd portion as a separate item

So how would I do this in javascript? Would I have to have a for loop that goes over the string checking if the scanner is inside a set of quotation marks? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Yes, I know. I was typing it in a hypothetical way where the entire he said hello world thing would be an entire string.

Comment: Do you want to handle escaped quotes? Btw, a parser would be easier to write :-)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but the script would "basically treating the quotation mark'd portion as a separate item"

Comment: Maybe `var string = 'he said "Hello World"';`? That's valid.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wanted to make it look more clear.

Comment: @user1858108: You could try regular expressions, but i think you want an easier way :)

Comment: @AndreiC: RegEx wouldn't work, they don't support lookbehind...

Comment: @AndreiC how would I plug a regex into the split() function or another way? I'm curious.

Comment: @lawm: I was suggesting the usage of regexp separately, so not in split

Comment: @Elliot: you are right, they are not standard supported; they can be mimicked (http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), but that's not the easy way ;). If the task is not that complex, split should do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```
var splitted = string.match(/(".*?")|(\S+)/g);
```

Basically it searches at first for strings with any characters between quotes (including spaces), and then all the remaining words in the string.

For example

`var string = '"This is" not a string "without" "quotes in it"';
string.match(/(".*?")|(\S+)/g);`

Returns this to the console:

```
[""This is"", "not", "a", "string", ""without"", ""quotes in it""]
```

Comment: +1 Seems like it meets OP's requirements. FWIW, you could shorten `[^\s]+` to `\S+`.

Comment: Rather more succinct than my solution. +1!

Comment: @VisioN to stop at the next ", you don't want a greedy match.

Comment: Since I am using the .* (that means, match any character), it would try to take as many characters as it can, including quotes! By appending the question mark, I force it to stop at the first quote it finds. In this case, the question mark is called lazy quantifier (as opposed to the normal greedy matching). Another way to achieve it would be to use [^"]* instead of .* (= match all but quotes)

Comment: Sorry for my dumbness, how does the string.match thing work? I will definitely accept this as an answer if somebody can help me out.

Comment: It uses [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which basically is a way to search for patterns inside strings. It has its set of rules that gives you the ability to create quite complex searches, but it has the disadvantage that as it grows, it becomes difficult to maintain due to its not-immediate readability

Comment: @4lbertoC So how can I apply this as a script? Can I assign a variable to the string.match thing and it will create an array?

Comment: Sure! If you do `var splitted = string.match(/(".*?")|(\S+)/g);` the result is stored into the `splitted` variable as an array, and you can use it in the rest of your code

Comment: Nevermind, W3Schools saves the day once again (okay please don't hate on me)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you mean this:

```
var string = 'he said "Hello World"';
```

Now that we've got that out of the way, you were partially correct with your idea of a for loop. Here's how I would do it:

```
// initialize the variables we'll use here
var string = 'he said "Hello World"', splitted = [], quotedString = "", insideQuotes = false;

string = string.split("");

// loop through string in reverse and remove everything inside of quotes
for(var i = string.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    // if this character is a quote, then we're inside a quoted section
    if(string[i] == '"') {
        insideQuotes = true;
    }

    // if we're inside quotes, add this character to the current quoted string and
    // remove it from the total string
    if(insideQuotes) {
        if(string[i] == '"' && quotedString.length > 0) {
            insideQuotes = false;
        }

        quotedString += string[i];
        string.splice(i, 1);
    }

    // if we've just exited a quoted section, add the quoted string to the array of
    // quoted strings and set it to empty again to search for more quoted sections
    if(!insideQuotes && quotedString.length > 0) {
        splitted.push(quotedString.split("").reverse().join(""));
        quotedString = "";
    }
}

// rejoin the string and split the remaining string (everything not in quotes) on spaces
string = string.join("");
var remainingSplit = string.split(" ");

// get rid of excess spaces
for(var i = 0; i<remainingSplit.length; i++) {
    if(remainingSplit[i].length == " ") {
        remainingSplit.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

// finally, log our splitted string with everything inside quotes _not_ split
splitted = remainingSplit.concat(splitted);
console.log(splitted);​
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways, but this produces an output exactly like what you specified. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/6nrgc/2/) a link to a working version of this in jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use this if people don't come up with a simpler alternative. This runs pretty fast, right?